# "Resource temporarily unavailable" when trying to connect to https websocket with ws-rs (mio)

Tags: sockets, ssl, websocket, rust, mio

I am trying to establish a secure connection using Rust [`ws-rs`](https://github.com/housleyjk/ws-rs) (based on mio).

The part of the code that I think is relevant:

```
impl ws::Handler for Client {
    fn on_message(&mut self, msg: ws::Message) -> ws::Result<()> {
        println!("msg = {}", msg);
        self.out.close(ws::CloseCode::Normal)
    }

    fn upgrade_ssl_client(
        &mut self,
        sock: TcpStream,
        _: &url::Url,
    ) -> ws::Result<SslStream<TcpStream>> {
        let mut builder = SslConnector::builder(SslMethod::tls()).map_err(|e| {
            ws::Error::new(
                ws::ErrorKind::Internal,
                format!("Failed to upgrade client to SSL: {}", e),
            )
        })?;
        builder.set_verify(SslVerifyMode::empty());

        let connector = builder.build()
            .configure()
            .unwrap()
            .use_server_name_indication(false)
            .verify_hostname(false)
            .connect("localhost:12321", sock)
            .unwrap();

        Ok(connector)
    }
}
```

A complete example is at [Github](https://github.com/mverleg/mwe_ws_rs_connectivity_issues/blob/master/rs_ws_ssl_server_client.rs), it's ~150 lines which is as small as I could get it.

I get this error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value:
WouldBlock(MidHandshakeSslStream {
    stream: SslStream {
        stream: TcpStream { addr: V4(127.0.0.1:52164), peer: V4(127.0.0.1:12321), fd: 12 },
        ssl: Ssl { state: "SSLv2/v3 read server hello A", verify_result: X509VerifyResult { code: 0, error: "ok" } }
    }, error: Error {
        code: ErrorCode(2),
        cause: Some(Io(Os {
            code: 11,
            kind: WouldBlock,
            message: "Resource temporarily unavailable"
        }))
    }
})
```

I don't really know what that means...

(I also created a ws-rs Github [issue](https://github.com/housleyjk/ws-rs/issues/247) last month as I thought it might be a problem with the lib or the example)